# "Skype is using the microphone" - I don't have Skype installed

Tags: kde

This is rather strange, why does it tell me that?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Teams installed?

Comment: Yes I do, this however shows up even if I'm not in any audio conversation on Teams. I can see what Microsoft did here... :(

Comment: Skype's eventually going to be EOL'd for Teams, as that's the preferred platform now per Microsoft.  It's not uncommon to see Skype and Teams say they're each other in the Microphone (because it's the same toolsets I think internally)

Comment: I guess that's the answer, anybody cares to post it so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Free points? I accept! The answer is Ubuntu thinks Teams is Skype. As a previous commenter said, they probably use something similar internally.

Comment: Welcome to AU. I think you’ll need to do a bit of original research to get the upvotes you want!!